# What should I do to test the business layer using Mockito?

Tags: spring-boot, mockito

I have a problem using mockito in my spring boot project. What should I do to test the business layer? (I only have the builder test).

public class ProductBuilder {

```
private Product product;
private Collection<Product> products;

public static ProductBuilder mockProductBuilder() {
    ProductBuilder builder = new ProductBuilder();
    builder.product = new Product("Beer", "Alcholic", "20,99", "Montez");

    return builder;
}

public static ProductBuilder mockCollectionProductBuilder() {
    ProductBuilder builder = new ProductBuilder();
    builder.products = new ArrayList<Product>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        Product product = new Product("Beer " + i, "Alcholic", "20,99" + i, "Montez");

        builder.products.add(product);
    }

    return builder;
}

// Methods
public Product  getProduct() {
    return this.product;
}

public Collection<Product> getProducts() {
    return this.products;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have test for your classes controllers, repositories and services. Your builder is fine, your controller should like something like

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class ProductControllerTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private ProductController productController;

    @Mock
    private ProductService productService;
    @Mock
    private BindingResult bindingResult;

    private Model model;

    private Product productOptional;
    private List<Product> products;
    private Product product;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
        this.productOptional = ProductBuilder.mockProductBuilder().getProduct();
        this.products = (List<Product>) ProductBuilder.mockCollectionProductBuilder().getProducts();
        this.product = ProductBuilder.mockProductBuilder().getProduct();

        this.model = new ConcurrentModel();
    }

    @Test
    public void index() {
        Mockito.when(this.productService.searchAll()).thenReturn(this.products);

        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.index(this.model), "product/index");
        Assert.assertEquals(this.model.containsAttribute("products"), true);
    }

    @Test
    public void create() {
        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.add(product, this.model), "product/addProduct");
    }


    @Test
    public void update() {
        Mockito.when(this.productService.searchById((long) 1)).thenReturn(this.productOptional);

        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.edit((long) 0, this.model), "product/editProduct");
        Assert.assertEquals(this.model.containsAttribute("product"), false); 
    }


    @Test
    public void save() {
        Mockito.when(this.productService.inserir(this.product)).thenReturn(this.product);
        Mockito.when(this.bindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.save(this.product, this.bindingResult, this.model), "product/addProduct");
    }

    @Test
    public void saveError() {
        Mockito.when(this.productService.inserir(this.product)).thenReturn(this.product);
        Mockito.when(this.bindingResult.hasErrors()).thenReturn(true);
        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.save(this.product, this.bindingResult, this.model), "product/addProduct");
    }

    @Test
    public void delete() {
        Assert.assertEquals(this.productController.delete((long) 1, this.model), "product/index");
        Mockito.verify(this.productService, Mockito.times(1)).deletar((long) 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For repositories

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
```

@SpringBootTest
public class ProductRepositoryTest {

```
@Autowired
private ProductRepository productRepository;

private Product product;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    this.product = ProductBuilder.mockProductBuilder().getProduct();  
}

@After
public void after() {
    this.productRepository.deleteAll();
}

@Test
public void findAll() {
    Assert.assertThat(this.productRepository.findAll(), instanceOf(List.class));
}

@Test
public void findById() {
    Assert.assertThat(this.productRepository.findById((long) 2), instanceOf(Optional.class));
}

@Test
public void saveCreate() {

    this.product.setId((long) 1);
    this.product = this.productRepository.save(this.product);
    //Assert.assertNotEquals(this.product.getId(), 1);
}

@Test
public void saveUpdate() {

    this.product.setId((long) 0);
    this.product = this.productRepository.save(this.product);
    this.product.setNome("Jonas");
    Product productAtualizado = this.productRepository.save(this.product);
    Assert.assertEquals(productAtualizado.getNome(), this.product.getNome());
} 

@Test
public void deleteById() {
    this.product = this.productRepository.save(this.product);
    this.productRepository.deleteById(this.product.getId());

    Assert.assertEquals(this.productRepository.findAll().size(), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Services

@SpringBootTest
public class ProductServiceTest {

```
@InjectMocks
private ProductService productService;

@Mock
private ProductRepository productRepository;

private Product productTest;
private List<Product> products;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    this.productTest = ProductBuilder.mockProductBuilder().getProduct();
    this.products = (List<Product>) ProductBuilder.mockCollectionProductBuilder().getProducts();
}

@Test
public void buscarTodosTest() {
    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(this.products);

    List<Product> productsBd = this.productService.buscarTodos();

    assertEquals(productsBd, this.products);
}

@Test
public void buscarPeloId() {
    Optional<Product> productOptional = Optional.of(this.productTest);
    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.findById(this.productTest.getId())).thenReturn(productOptional);

    Product product = this.productService.buscarPeloId(this.productTest.getId());

    assertEquals(product, productOptional.get());
}

@Test
public void inserirTest() {
    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.save(this.productTest)).thenReturn(this.productTest);

    Product productSalvo = this.productService.inserir(this.productTest);

    assertEquals(productSalvo, this.productTest);
}

@Test
public void atualizarTest() {
    Optional<Product> productOptional = Optional.of(this.productTest);
    this.productTest.setId((long) 1);

    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.save(this.productTest)).thenReturn(this.productTest);
    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.findById(this.productTest.getId())).thenReturn(productOptional);

    Product productAtualizado = this.productService.atualizar(this.productTest);

    assertEquals(productAtualizado, this.productTest);
}

@Test
public void deletarTest() {
    Optional<Product> productOptional = Optional.of(this.productTest);

    Mockito.when(this.productRepository.findById(this.productTest.getId())).thenReturn(productOptional);

    this.productService.deletar(this.productTest.getId());

    Mockito.verify(this.productRepository, Mockito.times(1)).findById(this.productTest.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="MyMusic">
<meta name="author" content="Victoria Brandt">

<title>Users - MyMusic</title>

</head>

<body>

<nav>

            <ul>
                <li><a href="/users">User</a></li>
                <li><a href="/musics">Music</a></li>
                <li><a href="/playlists">Playlist</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

  <div>
    <div >

        <div>
            <strong><h2>Users</h2></strong>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div >
            <a th:href="@{/users/addUser}" >Add new user</a>
        </div>
        </br>
        <div>
            <div >

                <table >
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>ID</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Location</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr th:each="user : ${users}">
                            <td th:text="${user.id}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.name}"></td>
                            <td th:text="${user.location}"></td>
                            <td >
                                <div >
                                    <a th:href="@{/users/editUser/{id}(id=${user.id})}" >Edit</a>
                                    <a class="delete btn btn-sm btn-danger" th:href="@{/users/deleteUser/{id}(id=${user.id})}">Delete</a>
                                </div>
                           </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="MyMusic">
<meta name="author" content="Victoria Brandt">

<title>Users - MyMusic</title>

</head>

<body>

    <nav> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/users">User</a></li>
            <li><a href="/musics">Music</a></li>
            <li><a href="/playlists">Playlist</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>


    <div>
        <div>

            <div>
                <strong><h2>Create new user</h2></strong>
            </div>
            </br>



            <div>
                <div>

                    <form th:object="${user}" th:action="@{/users/saveUser}"
                        method="POST">
                        <div>
                            <fieldset>
                                <div>
                                    <div th:if="${#fields.hasAnyErrors()}">
                                        <div th:each="detailedError : ${#fields.detailedErrors()}">
                                            <span th:text="${detailedError.message}"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div>
                                        <input type="text" id="id" th:field="*{id}" readOnly="readonly" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <div th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('name')}? 'has-error'">
                                        <label>Name</label> <input type="text" th:field="*{name}"
                                            autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <div
                                        th:classappend="${#fields.hasErrors('location')}? 'has-error'">
                                        <label>Location</label> <input type="text"
                                            th:field="*{location}" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <div >
                            <button type="submit" >Save</button>
                            <a th:href="@{/users}">Cancel</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```